# Three Way Quicksort for arrays with many duplicates: Partition Placement

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, divide-and-conquer

I'm working on a variation of the Quick Sort Algorithm designed to handle arrays where there may be many duplicate elements.  The basic idea is to divide the array into 3 partitions first: All Elements below the Pivot Values (with the initial pivot value being chosen at random); All Elements Equal to the Pivot Value; and All Elements Greater than the Pivot Value.

<strike>I need some advice regarding the best way to arrange the Partition.</strike>.

What is the best way to arrange the Partition in a Three Way Quick Sort?

The first way I might go about it is to just keep the Pivot Partition on the left, which would make it easy to define the boundaries when I return them to the larger Quick Sort function I plan to nest the Partition function within.  But that makes subsequent recursive calls to sort the Above and Below Partitions a little tricky, since they would be all lumped together in one large partition above the Pivot Partition to start with (instead of being more neatly organized into an Above and Below Partition).  I could call a For Loop to insert each of these elements above and below the Pivot Partition, but I suspect that would mitigate the efficiency of the algorithm.  After doing this, I could make two recursive calls to Quick Sort: once on the Below Partition, and again on the Above Partition.

OR I could modify Partition to insert "Below" elements to the left of the Pivot Partition, and insert "Above" elements to the right.  This reduces the need for linear scans over the array, but it means I would have to update the left and right bounds of the partition as the Partition function operates over the array.

I believe the second choice is the better one, but I want to see if anyone has any other ideas.

For reference, the initial array might look something like this:

```
array = [2, 2, 1, 9, 2]
```

Assuming the Pivot is randomly chosen as value of "2", then after Partition, it could look either like this:

```
array = [2, 2, 2, 9, 1]
```

Or like this if I insert above and below the partition during the Partition Function:

```
array = [1, 2, 2, 2, 9]
```

And the "shell code" I'm supposed to build this function around looks like this:

```
def randomized_quick_sort(a, l, r):
    if l >= r:
        return 
    k = random.randint(l, r)
    a[l], a[k] = a[k], a[l]
    left_part_bound, right_part_bound = partition3(a, l, r)
    randomized_quick_sort(a, l, left_part_bound - 1)
    randomized_quick_sort(a, right_part_bound + 1, r)
```

*The end result doesn't need to look like this (I just need to be able to output the right result and be able to resolve within a time limit to demonstrate minimal efficiency), but it shows why I think I may need to create Above and Below partitions as I'm creating the Pivot Partition.

Comment: `I need some advice` Please [ask an answerable question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: (Advice: [dual pivot quicksort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Multi-pivot_quicksort) is more useful than "3-way".)

Comment: I would recommend the second choice, except that the "below" and "equal" segments are both on the left and the "above" is on the right.  When they meet, the partitions will be in the right order, and you just need to sort below and above.  Note, this will not be a stable sort.  (But that's OK.)

Comment: @btilly  That's an interesting idea!  I don't think it's quite what the people who posed the problem had in mind, but I think that could work.  The only quibble is that it doesn't fully resolve the problem of having to sort many duplicate elements.  I think the idea is to avoid implementing the normal quick sort procedure on duplicate elements, since we could conceivably group them together and then just sort (the non-duplicates) around the pivot.

Comment: Did you look at the Dutch National Flag algorithm, also mentioned on the WP page that greybeard linked to? (Second paragraph of the [repeated elements subsection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Repeated_elements).)